# Having issues with passing arguments through function (Javascript)

Tags: javascript, function, arguments

I'm creating a function using Javascript where the user puts in two integers, and the function will output the smaller of the two integers:

```js
function minimum(num1, num2) {
    var num1 = document.getElementById('input1').value;
    var num2 = document.getElementById('input2').value;

    if(num1 < num2){
        document.getElementById('para').innerHTML = num1;
    }

    else if (num2 < num1){
        document.getElementById('para').innerHTML = num2;
    }

    else {
        document.getElementById('para').innerHTML = "There was something weird about your numbers. Please try again.";
    }

}
```

```css
body{
    background-color: #A9927D ;
    max-width: 900px;
    min-width: 600px;
}

h1{
    color: #F2F4F3;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 45px;
}

h3 {
    font-size: 20px;
    color: #F2F4F3;
}

.container{
    text-align: center;
}

.button-container {
    padding: 50px;
}

.bttn{
    height: 50px;
    border-radius: 40px;
    font-size: 20px;
    font-family:'Lucida Sans', 'Lucida Sans Regular', 'Lucida Grande', 'Lucida Sans Unicode', Geneva, Verdana, sans-serif;
    padding: 30px;
    background-color: #5E503F;
    box-shadow: 2px 2px 2px 2px #312A21;
    color: #F2F4F3;
}

.bttn:hover {


    background-color: #251F18;
}

.bttn:active {
    box-shadow: 0 1px 0px #251F18;

}

.npt {
    height: 40px;
    width: 100px;
}

#para{
    text-align: center;
    margin: auto;
    width: 40%;
    height: 100px;
    border: 1px solid #6E5E49;
    background-color: #9C8568;
    font-size: 20px;
    color:#F2F4F3;
}
```

```html
    <div class="container">
        <h1>Find the Minimum</h1>
        <h3>by Solange Wright</h2>
        <div class = "button-container">
            <input class = "npt" type="number" id = "input1"><br><br>
            <input class = "npt" type="number" id = "input2"><br><br><br><br>
            <span class = bttn onclick = "minimum(num1, num2)">Find</span>
        </div>

        <p id="para"></p>
    </div>
```

For some reason, I'm getting an error like this:

[image: Console says variable 'num1' is not defined]

How do I define `num1`? Is it an issue with data types? Does the `.value` method in Javascript do type coercion, or is there another additional step to make sure the two values are integers?

Answer (score 1):

You need to pass the id of the input.

Replace

```html
<span class="bttn" onclick="minimum(num1, num2)">Find</span>
```

with

```html
<span class"bttn" onclick="minimum('input1', 'input2')">Find</span>
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Remove the minimum parameters in the JS code (and also check if num1 and num2 are numbers)

   ```
    function minimum() {
      var num1 = document.getElementById('input1').value;
      var num2 = document.getElementById('input2').value;
      if (Number.isNaN(num1) || Number.isNaN(num2)){
         document.getElementById('para').innerHTML = "please insert valid numbers";
         return;
      }
      if(num1 < num2){
           document.getElementById('para').innerHTML = num1;
       }

       else if (num2 < num1){
           document.getElementById('para').innerHTML = num2;
       } 

       else {
           document.getElementById('para').innerHTML = "There was something weird about your numbers. Please try again.";
       }
    }
   ```
2. Refactor the button onclick not to pass paramters.

   ```
    <div class="container">
        <h1>Find the Minimum</h1>
        <h3>by Solange Wright</h2>
        <div class = "button-container">
            <input class = "npt" type="number" id = "input1"><br><br>
            <input class = "npt" type="number" id = "input2"><br><br><br><br>
            <span class = "bttn" onclick = "minimum()">Find</span>
        </div>
        <p id="para"></p>
    </div>
   ```

Answer (score 0):

It's generally [not a good idea](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Building_blocks/Events) to use inline event handlers. You can use one handler for the document and use a generic handler ([event delegation](https://javascript.info/event-delegation)). Doing so gives you the possibility to use everything you need within the handler function.

Furthermore, the submitted values have to be checked (do both input have values?) and converted to `Number` (retrieved input values are always strings).

Finally you can  use `Math` to [determine the smallest number](https://medium.com/@vladbezden/how-to-get-min-or-max-of-an-array-in-javascript-1c264ec6e1aa) in an array of numbers.

This brings us to (removed stuff to present a [minimum reproducable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)):

```js
document.addEventListener("click", getMinimalValue);
//       ^ add a click listener method document wide

function getMinimalValue(evt) {
  if (evt.target.id === "findSmallest") {
    const numbers = [
        document.querySelector("#input1").value || NaN,
        document.querySelector("#input2").value || NaN
      ]
      // ^ aggregate values into array (assign NaN if no value)
      .map(Number)
      // ^ convert values to Number (NaN will remain NaN)
      .filter(n => !isNaN(n));
      // ^ filter numbers only
    document.querySelector("#para").textContent =
      numbers.length < 2 ?
      //      ^ if not both entered values are numbers
      //        [numbers] array length is < 2
      "You did not enter two numeric values" :
      `Minimum of ${numbers.join(' and ')}: ${Math.min.apply(null, numbers)}`;
  }
}
```

```css
.npt {
  width: 50px;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}
```

```html
<input class="npt" type="number" id="input1">
<input class="npt" type="number" id="input2">
<span id="para"></span>
<br><button id="findSmallest">Find Minimum</button>
```